# Error Unknown encryption algorithm Cryptography RSACng

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, itextsharp, itext, rsa

estoy desarrollando en .Net Core 3.1 una funcionalidad que firma un documento PDF con un certificado .pfx, con apoyo en la libreria "iTextSharp.NetCore (v5.5.13.1)", el método es el siguiente:

```
 public void FirmaDocumento()
    {
        string rutaDocumento = @"C:\documento.pdf";
        string rutaDocumentoFirmado = @"C:\pdf_Firmado\documento.pdf";
        string rutaCertificado = @"C:\Certificados\********.pfx";
        string claveCertificado = "**********";

        X509Certificate2 certificado = new X509Certificate2(rutaCertificado, claveCertificado);

        X509CertificateParser objCP = new X509CertificateParser();
        Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate[] objChain = new Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate[] { objCP.ReadCertificate(certificado.RawData) };

        IList<ICrlClient> crlList = new List<ICrlClient>();
        crlList.Add(new CrlClientOnline(objChain));

        PdfReader objReader = new PdfReader(rutaDocumento);
        PdfStamper objStamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(objReader, new FileStream(rutaDocumentoFirmado, FileMode.Create), '\0', null, true);

        PdfSignatureAppearance signatureAppearance = objStamper.SignatureAppearance;
        signatureAppearance.Reason = "";
        signatureAppearance.Location = "";

        signatureAppearance.SetVisibleSignature(new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(100, 100, 300, 200), 1, null);

        IExternalSignature externalSignature = new X509Certificate2Signature(certificado, DigestAlgorithms.SHA1);

        MakeSignature.SignDetached(signatureAppearance, externalSignature, objChain, crlList, null, null, 0, CryptoStandard.CMS);

        if (objReader != null)
            objReader.Close();
        if (objStamper != null)
            objStamper.Close();
    }
```

El cual en la linea *IExternalSignature externalSignature = new X509Certificate2Signature(certificado, DigestAlgorithms.SHA1);* da el siguiente error:

*System.ArgumentException: Unknown encryption algorithm System.Security.Cryptography.RSACng*.

El mismo código si lo ejecuto en un proyecto *.NET Framework 4.8* si firma el documento correctamente.

La única diferencia que puede encontrar es que en una version el valor de **PrivateKey** del certificado *(X509Certificate2)* es **System.Security.Cryptography.RSACng** y en el otro es **System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider**

Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Pudiste solucionarlo?